# Unity fails to build Android player, throws single ambigous error

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

I try to build an android player, (worked like a charm yesterday), and I'm getting a single error when it fails

```
Build completed with a result of 'Failed' in 2 seconds (2401 ms)
Building Player failed
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent (int,intptr,bool&)
```

I looked into Editor logs, and it gives me the following stack trace:

```
Build completed with a result of 'Failed' in 2 seconds (2401 ms)
Building Player failed
UnityEngine.StackTraceUtility:ExtractStackTrace ()
UnityEngine.DebugLogHandler:LogFormat (UnityEngine.LogType,UnityEngine.Object,string,object[])
UnityEngine.Logger:Log (UnityEngine.LogType,object)
UnityEngine.Debug:LogError (object)
UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow/DefaultBuildMethods:BuildPlayer (UnityEditor.BuildPlayerOptions)
UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow:CallBuildMethods (bool,UnityEditor.BuildOptions)
UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow:GUIBuildButtons (UnityEditor.Modules.IBuildWindowExtension,bool,bool,bool,UnityEditor.Build.BuildPlatform,UnityEditor.Modules.IBuildPostprocessor)
UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow:ShowBuildTargetSettings ()
UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow:OnGUI ()
UnityEditor.HostView:InvokeOnGUI (UnityEngine.Rect)
UnityEditor.DockArea:DrawView (UnityEngine.Rect)
UnityEditor.DockArea:OldOnGUI ()
UnityEngine.UIElements.IMGUIContainer:DoOnGUI (UnityEngine.Event,UnityEngine.Matrix4x4,UnityEngine.Rect,bool,UnityEngine.Rect,System.Action,bool)
UnityEngine.UIElements.IMGUIContainer:HandleIMGUIEvent (UnityEngine.Event,UnityEngine.Matrix4x4,UnityEngine.Rect,System.Action,bool)
UnityEngine.UIElements.IMGUIContainer:HandleIMGUIEvent (UnityEngine.Event,System.Action,bool)
UnityEngine.UIElements.IMGUIContainer:HandleIMGUIEvent (UnityEngine.Event,bool)
UnityEngine.UIElements.IMGUIContainer:SendEventToIMGUIRaw (UnityEngine.UIElements.EventBase,bool,bool)
UnityEngine.UIElements.IMGUIContainer:SendEventToIMGUI (UnityEngine.UIElements.EventBase,bool,bool)
UnityEngine.UIElements.IMGUIContainer:ProcessEvent (UnityEngine.UIElements.EventBase)
UnityEngine.UIElements.CallbackEventHandler:HandleEvent (UnityEngine.UIElements.EventBase)
UnityEngine.UIElements.CallbackEventHandler:HandleEventAtCurrentTargetAndPhase (UnityEngine.UIElements.EventBase)
UnityEngine.UIElements.CallbackEventHandler:HandleEventAtTargetPhase (UnityEngine.UIElements.EventBase)
UnityEngine.UIElements.MouseCaptureDispatchingStrategy:DispatchEvent (UnityEngine.UIElements.EventBase,UnityEngine.UIElements.IPanel)
UnityEngine.UIElements.EventDispatcher:ApplyDispatchingStrategies (UnityEngine.UIElements.EventBase,UnityEngine.UIElements.IPanel,bool)
UnityEngine.UIElements.EventDispatcher:ProcessEvent (UnityEngine.UIElements.EventBase,UnityEngine.UIElements.IPanel)
UnityEngine.UIElements.EventDispatcher:ProcessEventQueue ()
UnityEngine.UIElements.EventDispatcher:OpenGate ()
UnityEngine.UIElements.EventDispatcherGate:Dispose ()
UnityEngine.UIElements.EventDispatcher:ProcessEvent (UnityEngine.UIElements.EventBase,UnityEngine.UIElements.IPanel)
UnityEngine.UIElements.EventDispatcher:Dispatch (UnityEngine.UIElements.EventBase,UnityEngine.UIElements.IPanel,UnityEngine.UIElements.DispatchMode)
UnityEngine.UIElements.BaseVisualElementPanel:SendEvent (UnityEngine.UIElements.EventBase,UnityEngine.UIElements.DispatchMode)
UnityEngine.UIElements.UIElementsUtility:DoDispatch (UnityEngine.UIElements.BaseVisualElementPanel)
UnityEngine.UIElements.UIElementsUtility:UnityEngine.UIElements.IUIElementsUtility.ProcessEvent (int,intptr,bool&)
UnityEngine.UIElements.UIEventRegistration:ProcessEvent (int,intptr)
UnityEngine.UIElements.UIEventRegistration/<>c:<.cctor>b__1_2 (int,intptr)
UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent (int,intptr,bool&)
```

I am totally lost on the fix. I haven't installed any new packages , just fixed few bugs I found after testing yesterday's build.

Version of Unity: 2022.3.4f1

P.S.
Building for Windows works normal. I restarted unity, restarted my PC, I cleared project meta data, and reset player settings, tried different combinations of build settings also, there is no compilation error in scripts.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: For anyone who stumbles upon the same problem, I can only say that rolling back to the previous version worked fine. Something broke with the project and as of writing this comment I haven't found a fix. Rolled back the change I made with one of the bugs, and everything works again. Implementing the same fix again does not break it.